# Why can't I edit C# script although I have monodevelop installed in Unity3D 4.3.4?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scripting, monodevelop

I am making a game,

I put the background and player; all fine, but when it comes to editing and double-clicking on the "script C#" named "player" it show me:

> Unable to open Assets/Scripts/Player.cs: Check external application preferences.

I read about this over the internet, but i guess the answers were for older versions as they said to install Monodevelop.

I have the Unity3D 4.3.4 and Monodevelop comes built-in with it. I installed "Winmerge" as as revision control.

I tried restarting Unity3D, my game, Winmerge... but I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Did you solve your problem already? Maybe you can share your experience with us?

Comment: @亚历山大 Please do not add irrelevant tags to questions. [tag:unity] is not about the Unity Game Engine.

Comment: This is a convention used on this stack exchange. Unity3d is no game engine because it is just `unity`. Unity3d is the name of the website. I checked the tag and your right but thats not correct ;)

Comment: @亚历山大 The unity tag is used here for something entirely different. Whether or not "unity3d" is the "correct name" for the game engine is irrelevant, the ***correct tag*** that should be used on these questions is [tag:unity3d].

Comment: @TZHX Like I said, its the convention of this website. Like you should understand from my post, I'm aware of whats going on, but thanks for repeating everything again ;)

Answer (score 4):

Check your script editor preferences and see if it needs to be set.  It should say "MonoDevelop (built-in)"

Edit > Preferences... (around the middle of the menu) > External Tools > External Script Editor

Answer (score 2):

You might need to right click a script and click "Sync MonoDevelop Project" before you can open the script for editing by double clicking it. You only have to do this once. I use VCS 2010 Express, and I do that, and then open the solution file generated by unity (in the root folder of the unity project) with VCS. Should work the same way for MonoDevelop, only you can also double click the script in Unity to open it with MonoDevelop.